# Html Converted into PDF Not Showing Unicode Characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, unicode, itext

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
             "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.pdf");
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

StringReader html = new StringReader(sb.ToString());

byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

Response.Clear();
using (iTextSharp.text.Document document = new iTextSharp.text.Document())
{
      PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, Response.OutputStream);
      document.Open();
      iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(
      writer, document, stream, new System.Text.UTF8Encoding()
   );
}
Response.End();
```

So, what could be the reason that pdf doesn't display unicode characted since I have

```
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
```

and

```
.ParseXHtml(writer, document, stream, new System.Text.UTF8Encoding());
```

Comment: Sanity Check: does your font contain the requested Unicode characters?

Comment: See this for setting the "default" font as @Jongware said: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19560305/231316

Answer (score 1):

[**Here is the few steps to display unicode characters in converting Html to Pdf**](http://www.codescratcher.com/asp-net/display-unicode-characters-in-converting-html-to-pdf/)

1. Create a HTMLWorker
2. Register a unicode font and assign it
3. Create a style sheet and set the encoding to Identity-H
4. Assign the style sheet to the html parser
5. Check below code

   ```
       TextReader reader = new StringReader(html);
       Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 30, 30, 30, 30);
       PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Create));
       HTMLWorker worker = new HTMLWorker(document);
       document.Open();
       FontFactory.Register("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\ARIALUNI.TTF", "arial unicode ms");
       iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet ST = new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet();
       ST.LoadTagStyle("body", "encoding", "Identity-H");
       worker.Style = ST;
       worker.StartDocument();
   ```

**Check below link for more understanding....**

- [**Display Unicode characters in converting Html to Pdf**](http://www.codescratcher.com/asp-net/display-unicode-characters-in-converting-html-to-pdf/)

Hindi, Turkish, and special characters are also display during converting from HTML to PDF using this method. Check below demo image.

[image]

Comment: Character is coming but when you will try a word in marathi it would not come

Comment: Cant display hindi characters